# What executes instructions for a process: the kernel or the cpu?

Tags: kernel, process

Computer Systems: a Programmer's Perspective says:

> [image]
>
> Figure 8.14 shows an example of context switching between a pair of
> processes A and B. In this example, initially process A is running in
> user mode until it traps to the kernel by executing a read system
> call. The trap handler in the kernel requests a DMA transfer from the
> disk controller and arranges for the disk to interrupt the processor
> after the disk controller has ﬁnished transferring the data from disk
> to memory.
>
> The disk will take a relatively long time to fetch the data (on the
> order of tens of milliseconds), so instead of waiting and doing
> nothing in the interim, the kernel performs a context switch from
> process A to B. Note that, before the switch, **the kernel** is executing
> instructions in user mode on behalf of process A (i.e., there is no
> separate kernel process). During the ﬁrst part of the switch, **the
> kernel** is executing instructions in kernel mode on behalf of process
> A. Then at some point it begins executing instructions (still in
> kernel mode) on behalf of process B. And after the switch, **the kernel**
> is executing instructions in user mode on behalf of process B.
>
> Process B then runs for a while in user mode until the disk sends an
> interrupt to signal that data have been transferred from disk to
> memory. The kernel decides that process B has run long enough and
> performs a context switch from process B to A, returning control in
> process A to the instruction immediately following the read system
> call. Process A continues to run until the next exception occurs, and
> so on.

What does "**the kernel** is executing instructions in user/kernel mode on behalf of a process" mean?

Isn't it that only the cpu   executes instructions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is only the CPU that executes instructions.

I’m not sure what the author was trying to explain here with that particular phrase...

Comment: Thanks.  (1) A process is an instance of a program. Is "kernel" a program? If yes, what is the thing similar to process for "kernel"?  (2) In the quote for context switching, is the kernel program  executed at some point? Or only the programs of the two processes are executed?

Comment: I don't see anything unclear about that phrasing; it's syntactically and semantically no different to "the program is executing a function".

Comment: @MichaelHomer I get that, but what does the kernel execute in user mode on behalf of processes before and after a context switch?

Comment: @Tim (1) arguably yes, but it has a rather special role, and runs before any processes and, once processes exist, in all processes as necessary. (2) Processes run program code and kernel code, depending on the circumstances. During a context switch, process A switch to kernel mode, running kernel code; at some point the kernel reschedules, and execution switches to process B, and when the kernel code returns, execution resumes in the program code for process B.